# clickonce (in .NETv3.5) - does it support working through a proxy server with username and password?

Tags: clickonce

Does ClickOnce (in VS2008, .NETv3.5) support working through a proxy server with username and password?

thanks

PS.  Just tried it and it seems is does not?  I got the following errors:

(a) Under firefox:

```
URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2147024891'
```

(b) under IE

System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)

```
 --- Inner Exception ---
System.Net.WebException
 - The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
 - Source: System
 - Stack trace:
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
  at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
```

PS.  The info in the link belows suggeset it does not fully & robustly - [link text](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/115468/click-once-fails-with-proxy-authentication)

Answer (score 1):

The longer answer is no, but there's a workaround for it. This has been sanctioned by the C/O PM at MSFT.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/3e9cebad-9630-4bbc-a0ca-0d2f20335454

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, it doesn't.  This was a problem for me back in October (I even left a comment on the Microsoft Connect page you linked to above.)

My problem stemmed from the fact that my company has an application that is used both internally within our intranet and externally for users outside of our office.  Since there are users outside our office I had to publish the application to an internet (i.e. non-intranet) location.

When corporate changed a few proxy settings, the application broke for our internal users ability to install and update the application because their proxy credentials were being invalidated ever 5 minutes.  They could load the application so long as the first opened IE and let any external web page load-- something that seemed to automatically re-validate their credentials.

The best solution I could find was to publish the application twice-- first to the external website location.  Second, to an intranet friendly location that wasn't validated through the proxy.

This solution certainly isn't elegant but it worked for us.